# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when starting apache spark notebook

Tags: apache-spark, spark-notebook

When attempt to run spark-notebook.bat I receive below exception :

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorSta
ticBinder]
[warn] application - Start local micro tachyon
Oops, cannot start the server.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Under File System Factory found for: C:\U
sers\AppData\Local\Temp\Tachyon1231915320514495869U1443990536027
```

Is tachyon and hadoop a requirement for running ?

Are there documented steps for running on Windows ?